# How to replace a fan on a 3com SuperStack 4500 unit (and where to find a fan)?

Tags: switch, 3com, fan

I have a couple 3com SuperStack 4500 switches with failed fans.   I am not having luck locating information on HOW to actually replace the fans, or where to find a replacement/what kind.

I know what to do, but was hoping there is some information out there as I will likely delegate this task to someone and it would help if they could read some documentation.

Plus if I cant find the specific type of fan to buy, it means I have to take the unit apart first (which is at a remote location) just to determine what kind of fan is in it.

Comment: Seems likely that these are EOL, since the company hasn't existed for 4 years.  If anyone knew it would be HP, though I doubt they are supported anymore.  There seem to be lots of these type of switches on ebay.  Pick up a few old ones and cannibalize them.

Comment: Indeed, second hand ones on eBay are between $20 and $50 in AU and things are normally over-priced here, so in the US they should be cheaper. Buy a few and take the fans out of them. It would probably cost that much to buy an OEM or 3rd party replacement fan.

Comment: If one of you goes ahead and answers this, I will accept - I did not realize these used units were so cheap.   Not even worth replacing the fan, I will just buy a used 'fully working' unit.  I can even buy a bigger unit for around the same price!